# Trying to Format a Field in SAS, ignoring the decimals

Tags: sas, data-analysis

I am trying to format a particular field in the below format:
If the value is 60.00 it has to be displayed as 60.
if the value is 14.32 it has to displayed as 1432
and if it is 0.00 then output should be 0
i.e. No decimal should be Displayed.

Below is the datasets and the option i have tried.

```
data input_dataset;
 input srno $ bill_amt $10.;
 datalines;
 1 60.00
 2 0.00
 3 14.32
 ;
 run;



data test;
 set input_dataset;
 format mc062 $10.;
 mc062 = put((bill_amt *100 ),10.);
```

### run;

```
     expected Results are:
     mc062:
     60
     0
     1432
```

Comment: Why are you reading it in with a character informat into a character variable, as opposed to reading it into a numeric field?

Comment: WHY?  How are you going to tell the difference between `1.23` and `123`?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
data input_dataset;
input srno $ bill_amt ;
datalines;
1 60.00
2 0.00
3 14.32
;
run;

data output_dataset;
set input_dataset;
if (bill_amt NE int(bill_amt))then bill_amt = bill_amt * 100;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A custom `PICTURE` format will scale a data value prior to rendering the digits according to the picture template.

This example has a template for values up to 12 digits after scaling.

```
proc format;
  picture nodecimals 
    0 = '9'
    other='000000000000'   /* 12 digit selectors */
    (mult=100)             /* value scaling multiplier */
  ;
run;

data have;
 input srno $ bill_amt ;  * get some NUMERIC billing amounts;

 format bill_amt 10.2;    * format to be used when showing value;

 * copy amount into bill_raw (no format) just for learning about 
 * the effect of a format (or not) in output produced for viewing;
 bill_raw = bill_amt;     

 * copy amount in mc062 variable that will custom PICTURE format applied
 * when output (for viewing) is produced;
 mc062 = bill_amt;
 format mc062 nodecimals.;

 datalines;
 1 60.00
 2 0.00
 3 14.32
 4 123.456
 ;
 run;

* produce some output for viewing;
proc print data=have;
run;
```